# pip is rolling back

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I have a problem with the pip python 3.x installation. 
I have pip version 19.0.3, but when i use pycharm, it keeps saying that i need the pip updated.

when i check the folder, I can see there is another version of pip pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg in the folder.

I remember ticking the option to add the python in the environment path when i installed python.

When I tried to update/install pip again, i got the error.

```
(venv) C:\Users\ranic\PycharmProjects\ProjectDatabase>pip help install
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\Users\r\PycharmProjects\ProjectDatabase>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\r\pycharmprojects\projectdatabase\venv\lib\site-packages (19.0.3)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the error message in a formatted code block in your question. Images of code are hard to read and links to images could change or be broken in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check, I guarantee that `pip` is not in the same place as `python`.

Mine are, seen below:

```
C:\Users\adsmith>where pip
C:\Users\adsmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe

C:\Users\adsmith>where python
C:\Users\adsmith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

but I'm guessing your `python` is referring to Python2, and `pip` Python3 (or vice versa). If you find the version of Python that `pip` refers to, you should be able to do:

```
path/to/that/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```